# Conditional continuous probability on a fixed point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I was asked to show the following statement:

Let $X, Y$ both be equally distributed random variables on $[0,1]$, we define

$$ P(\{Y \leq y\}|\{X=x\}) = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} P(\{Y \leq y\}|\{x \leq X \leq x+h \}).  $$

Show that
$$ P(\{Y \leq g(X) \}|\{X=x\}) = g(x)$$.

$$----$$

We haven't covered joint probability distribution functions yet. In the end I got stuck at evaluating

$$ P(\{Y \leq g(X)\} \cap \{x\leq X \leq x+h\})$$

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed and independent, you can calculate the probability of any event involving $X$ and $Y$ by finding the area of that event, divided by the area of the rectangle where $X$ and $Y$ live. In this case, $X$ and $Y$ live on the unit square defined by $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le 1$, and the event $\{Y\le g(X)\cap x\le X\le x+h\}$ is the area below the curve $y=g(x)$ between $x$ and $x+h$. You can relate the limit as $h\to0$ to certain calculus concepts.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for the reply, how should we argue formally by using the definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in [0, 1]$, we have
$$P(Y \leq g(X) \mid X = x) = P(Y \leq g(x) \mid X = x).$$

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can say further that $P(Y \leq g(x) \mid X = x) = P(Y \leq g(x))$, so
$$P(Y \leq g(X) \mid X = x) = P(Y \leq g(x)).$$
Now, assuming that $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, we get
$$P(Y \leq g(X) \mid X = x) = P(Y \leq g(x)) = g(x).$$

Edit: Here is the approach computing the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}P(Y \leq g(X) \mid x_0 \leq X \leq x_0 + h)$ directly:
\begin{align}
P(Y \leq g(X), x_0 \leq X \leq x_0 + h) &= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}I(y \leq g(x), x_0 \leq x \leq x_0 + h)\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h}\int_{0}^{1}I(y \leq g(x))\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h}g(x)\,dx,
\end{align}
and
$$P(x_0 \leq X \leq x_0 + h) = h.$$
So
$$\lim_{h \to 0}P(Y \leq g(X) \mid x_0 \leq X \leq x_0 + h) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h}g(x)\,dx = g(x_0)$$
assuming $g$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but $P(\{Y \leq y\}|\{X=x\})$ is defined using limit in the problem, is it favorable to not use it and just continue as in your solution?

Comment: @hteica If you must use that limit definition rather than the classical definition, then I would try to justify the steps in my answer using the limit definition. E.g., justify that $$P(Y \leq g(X) \mid X = x) = P(Y \leq g(x) \mid X = x).$$ Or just show altogether that the limit definition equals the classical one in this case.

Comment: I tried using the limit definition to prove that one step, but didn't really work out, do you have any ideas?

Comment: We have $P(\{Y \leq g(X) \} | \{x \leq X \leq x+h\}) = P(\{Y \leq g(X) \} \cap \{x \leq X \leq x+h\})$, by taking the limit from the positive direction we get non-increasing sets and since $P$ is continuous in this sense, the expression is equal to $P(\{Y \leq g(X) \} \cap \{x=X\})$ and as the last step we can just rewrite $X$ with $x$ and get rid of the superfluous condition $X=x$. I think this should work, right?

Comment: @hteica No, we have $P(Y \leq g(X) \mid x \leq X \leq x + h) = \frac{P(Y \leq g(X), x \leq X \leq x + h)}{P(x \leq X \leq x + h)}$. They key to finishing is to divide both numerator and denominator by $h$ and then use the fundamental theorem of calculus. This will show that $P(Y \leq g(X) \mid X = x)$ is equal to the classical definition.

Comment: What do you mean by the classical definition? And how do we use the fundamental theorem of calculus since there's no integral? I know $P(\{ a \leq X \leq b \})$ can be written as integral (by definition), but how do we unfold the definition with two inequalities as constrains?

Comment: The numerator converges to $P(\{Y \leq g(X)\} \cap \{x \leq X \leq x\})$ but the denominator $h$ converges to $0$, does this mean we have infinity?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but my problem is in the following step, I don't know how to justify the double integral equality.

Comment: @hteica I added the computation for this problem to my answer. The classical definition is the one on page 205 here https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf.  Example 4.1.6. on page 209 shows the definition given to undergraduates, which is relevant here.

Comment: @hteica If $X$ and $Y$ are independent with densities $f_X, f_Y$, then it is easy to check that $(X, Y)$ has density $f_{(X, Y)}(x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Here I implicitly use Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: Yes I can see the difficulty here, my professor didn't define the probability using Lebesgue integral, but instead we defined $P(\{a \leq X \leq b \}$ as a single variable integral from $a$ to $b$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136409/discussion-between-mason-and-hteica).

Answer (score 2):

When $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed on$[0,1]$, the probability of an event involving $X$ and $Y$ is the area of the region described by that event. If you draw out the region described by the event $\{Y \leq g(X)\} \cap \{x\leq X \leq x+h\}$, we see it is the area below the curve $y=g(x)$ between $x$ and $x+h$. Using the fact that that area is given by a certain integral, we get
$$
P(\{Y \leq g(X)\} \cap \{x\leq X \leq x+h\})=\int_x^{x+h}g(t)\,\mathrm dt\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{h \downarrow 0} P(\{Y \leq y\}|\{x \leq X \leq x+h \})=\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{P(\{Y \leq g(X)\} \cap \{x\leq X \leq x+h\})}{P(x\le X\le x+h)}=\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}g(t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
This fact that this limit equals $g(x)$ is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

---

The only place where my argument lacks rigor is when I stated $(1)$. I am not sure how you are expected to justify this; it is a pretty low-level measure theoretic result.

Comment: Thanks, yes my exact problem is also in justifying (1) formally, I mean intuitively its pretty clear but my aim is to derive it from the definitions.

Comment: @hteica I need more context to help you. How has this course been taught, did you start by rigorously establishing measure theory, or was that not mentioned?

Comment: Yes we started with measure theory, we had Borel, etc, also some definitions of the probabilistic function. and then discrete, continuous variables. But still nothing on joint probability distribution functions.